# Is an api call needed at all for data access with blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

So I was thinking instead of the traditional model:

1. Create a service
2. Inject the DBContext in the service
3. Create a controller, inject the service in the controller
4. Call the controller method to access the data from the razor component

Since you can inject the service directly in the razor component, why not do that and handle the authorization directly in the service?

Would that cause security issues?

Would it be possible to extract the connection string if the code gets debugged via the browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Razor Components there are two modes of execution: On the client browser (Blazor), and on the server (previously called server-side Blazor). When your app is hosted on the client browser, you can presently access your database only through AJAX; that is HttpClient, which requires you to create a web API project that can access your database (directly or through services and repositories, etc.) and returns required data.

As you can see, though the front end Blazor app is running on the client (C# on the client), you cannot access your database directly as your database resides on the server. Authentication can only be and should be employed on the server, and requires AJAX calls.

When your app is hosted on the server (ASP.NET Core application only), you may employ to methods to access your database. Creating a service that query the database and returns data directly to the calling Components App. This is possible because the Components App project, and the hosting ASP.NET Core application resides on the server. No need for Web API here... However, you can create a Web API which serves the data even in this case. Authentication and Authorization should be the same as in traditional ASP.NET Core Web application.

ASP.NET team has stated that switching from client side Blazor to server side Blazor should be done by modifying a couple of code lines. This is partially true, and can be misleading. You have to design your app from the very beginning based on the mode of execution you expect to use. Personally, I would recommend using Web API in both execution models. So that switching from one mode to another can be as easy as ASP.NET team says. Again, if you create a service that directly accesses your database and returns data to the calling Components App, you cannot run this code in browser mode of execution, as the database is on the server and your service "is running" on the client. So designing your applications and knowing before hand how and where it should be used is of great importance. I'm of the opinion that services instead of Web API should only be used in Intranet applications.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created a repo: https://github.com/Holo00/BergerFlowTrading .

Comment: In this case, the LoginSubmit page gets injected, the IdentityService which is injected the DbContext. Access to the database seems to work in this case.So, since the DBContext is injected in the client if I created an IQueryable, up to that point everything gets executed client side, once I call a ToList() on the IQueryable, the query gets sent to the db server directly and it returns the result to the client. Is that right?

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Berger, Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you out... Your comment above is actually a new question, so please move it to a new question, and I'll answer it soon. Thanks...

Comment: When you use intranet I know the meaning of the term but is it because of not many users that will be using app, or what is the reason why you reccomend it only in that case? I am currently working on app that will be used in company under VPN and it will be used by only 2 or 3 people so creating all APIs and all DTOs seams unnecesary overhead as compared to just injection some service